# function for displaying a menu item in php

Tags: php, menu

I met some trouble with a php function customed by myself.

In fact I would like to separated the html code from the php treatment, so Instead of displaying each element one after one, I decided to put my menu into an array.

So here is my array:

```
function getAccess($var){
   $data=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `acces` WHERE `id`='.$var.'")); 
   return $data;
}
getAccess($_SESSION['id']);

    $paramAcces = array(
    'comptesfinanciers' => array(
        'libelle'   => 'COMPTES FINANCIERS',
        'acces'     => $data['comptesfinanciers'],
        'lien'      => 'financier',
        'image'     => 'images/finances.png'
    ),
     'journaux' => array(
        'libelle'   => 'JOURNAUX',
        'acces'     => $data['journaux'],
        'lien'      => 'journaux',
        'image'     => 'images/newspaper.png'
    )
    );




/**
 * AFFICHAGE DE LA SECTION PARAMETRES SUR LA PAGE D'ACCUEIL
 */
 function affichParam($paramAccees){
foreach ($paramAcces as &$parametres) {   
    echo '<ul class="getcash-vmenu"><li><a href="index.php?p='.$parametres['lien'].'" class="active"><span class="t"><img src="'.$parametres['image'].'"> '.$parametres['libelle'].'</span></a></li></ul>';
 }
 }
```

The trouble is that when I call this function like that in the main page index.php

```
affichParam($paramAccees)
```

It does not display anything except a semicolon like that ;

Anykind of help or advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to pass `$paramAcces` like `affichParam($paramAcces)`

Comment: Did the semicolon finally disappear?

Comment: yes Sir, in fact it was outside of the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in this code block

```
function affichParam($paramAccees){
  foreach ($paramAcces as &$parametres) {   
    echo '<ul class="getcash-vmenu"><li><a href="index.php?p='.$parametres['lien'].'" class="active"><span class="t"><img src="'.$parametres['image'].'"> '.$parametres['libelle'].'</span></a></li></ul>';
  }
}
```

Change the first line to this:

```
function affichParam($paramAcces){
```

**EDIT:**

And also what @GBD commented, call `affichParam($paramAcces)` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

i suppose your code must meet all these preconditions:
- The result of your SELECT statement is not empty
- your return value of the function call getAccess($_SESSION['id']) is stored into $data like this:

```
$data = getAccess(...);
```

- why do you use the reference &$parameters in your affichParam(). simply use: 
  foreach($paramAccess as $parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You made mistake in $paramAccess. Try this:

```
function affichParam($paramAccess){
  foreach ($paramAccess as $parametres) {   
    echo '<ul class="getcash-vmenu"><li><a href="index.php?p='.$parametres['lien'].'" class="active"><span class="t"><img src="'.$parametres['image'].'"> '.$parametres['libelle'].'</span></a></li></ul>';
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks I've read the comment of CBD, this mistake has been corrected